# CodeIgniter - Maintain complex URL routing

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, routes

I want to maintain a complex URL structure while routing. I could not write routing for the following requirement.

If the URL comes with `http://localhost/api/cals/func/id` I want to route it to `http://localhost/api/cals/func/id`, otherwise I want to route the URL to `http://localhost/home/`.

I tried this but it is not working in all use cases.

```
$route['api/(:any)'] = 'api/(:any)';

$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index/';
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you;
You must use `$1` for it.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index/';

$route['api/(:any)'] = 'api/$1';

$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index/';
```